# selectbox with one option detect selection

Tags: jquery, html

Suppose I have a selectbox **X** with **n > 1** options like this:

```
<select id="X">
    <option...
    .
    .
    .
    ...</option>
</select>
```

Now suppose I have another selectbox **Y** that only has only **1** option in it like this:

```
<select id="Y">
    <option value="someValue">Some Value</option>
</select>
```

But other options could be added to the selectbox *dynamically*.

I use

```
$("#X").change(/*some code here*/);
$("#Y").change(/*some other code here*/);
```

to detect whenever an option is changed to display some view that corresponds to the currently selected option in the selectbox.
But whenever selectbox **Y** contains only **one** option and the user clicks on this option after he lost focus on this selectbox, obviously `$("#Y").change()` would not be triggered.

I want something that would trigger again when a user just makes a selection, regardless of what's currently selected in the selectbox.

Here is a screenshot of the selectbox containing one option: [image: http://puu.sh/aEqcs/0eb2f7d341.png]
So suppose the user selects something from box **X** and something happens, now user selects the only option available from box **Y**. Now the same code has to be run as in `$("#Y").change(/*some other code here*/);`. What's the best approach here?

Comment: Sounds like you just want a `focus()` event handler.

Comment: When the selectbox has focus, nothing should happen. Only when the user actively 'selected' an option. When using `focus()`, I would have to user some boiler code to check all these conditions. Isn't there a more elegant way of handling this?

Comment: If there's no change, there's no change event. :-)

Comment: I'm searching for some kind of '*selected*' event.

Comment: What about the `click` event?

Comment: Well, I could combine the `focus` and `click` event, to be triggered *only* when the selectbox has **one** option?

Comment: Or perhaps using the `blur` event, and just checking `$(this).val()` within the blur?  (Still a bit crap, as nothing will happen until the user clicks off the select box...  perhaps a fancy select plugin would better meet your needs...)

Comment: @DaveSalomon Would you know one such fancy plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well guess I have to replace

```
$("#Y").change(/*some other code here*/);
```

with

```
$(document).on("click", '#Y option', function() {
    /*some other code here*/
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I put together this JSFiddle, It triggers a change event on click, but only when the select box is open. Only one problem, when the user actually changes the option the click event still gets fired. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5UQh3/1/)

HTML

```
<select id="Y">
    <option value="someValue">Some Value</option>
    <option value="someOtherValue">Some Other Value</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
//For this to work Values must be Unique.

var $isOpen = false;//flag to tell if select box is open or closed.
var $selectedItem;//The selected item before user clicks their option
$('#Y').click(function () {
    if ($isOpen) {
        $('#Y').trigger('change', true);
        $isOpen = false;
    } else {
        //this is needed as we only want to detect the users 2nd click, when selectbox is open.
        $isOpen = true;
        //set the currently selected item
        $selectedItem = $("#Y option:selected").val();
    }
});

$("#Y").blur(function () {
    //detect when user doesn't click second time and set to false
    $isOpen = false;
});

$("#Y").change(function (evt, wasTrigged) {
    //check if this change event was triggered in code
    if (wasTrigged) {
        //Check if the option value had changed from when the user clicked Select Box        
        if ($("#Y option:selected").val() === $selectedItem) {
            console.log("Select Item Never Changed");
        }
    } else {
        //When a user actually changes to a different option.
        console.log("User Changed");
    }
});
```